# How to extract date from JSON with year, day and month as separate fields in format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: java, json, date

I am new to JSON, to get transaction details of user i am making API call to one of the webservice in the JSON response from the API the transaction date is coming as below

```
   {
    "trasanction_date": {
        "year": 2021,
        "month": 6,
        "day": 16
    }
}
```

I need to convert the above date in format yyyy-mm-dd to insert it into Cassandra. Right now how i am converting is, i am creating new JSONObject from above String like

```
JSONObject trasaction = new JSONObject("{\"trasanction_date\":{\"year\":2021,\"month\":6,\"day\":16}}");

JSONObject date = trasaction.get("trasaction_date");

String year = date.getString("year");
String month = date.getString("month");
String day = date.getString("day");

//concatenating the final result to frame the date
String transactionDate = year+month+Day
```

Is there a way to efficiently convert the above JSON in format yyyy-mm-dd with out extracting and concatenating the string. Please help with above thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need a little more to match the desired pattern (you are missing the hyphens and not enforcing number of digits for month and day - consider using String.format(String,Object...).  Consider using java.time.LocalDate if your data model is more than a pass-through from client to DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `TransactionDate.java` class witch contains three String fields `year`, `month`,`day` with getters and setters. Then, create`TransactionDetails.java` class witch have property of type `TransactionDate` and use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to convert JSON string to java object.
You can take a look at this [article](https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-serializedname/) to see how to use `gson`

Then inside `TransactionDate.java` class you can override `toString()` method to something like this :

```
@Override
String toString() {
  return this.year + " " + this.month + " " + this.day;
}
```

Finally, instad of returning `transactionDate` string you can get `TransactionDate` object from `TransactionDetails` and return it's String representation.

Comment: @user13906258 great!!